# How to wait until EXTERNAL-IP is assigned?

Tags: kubernetes, ansible, envoyproxy

When I deploy https://projectcontour.io/ ingress controller on my Digital Ocean K8S cluster, a load balancer gets created automatically.

I consider to use Ansible as management tool for K8S to automate the deployment.

After the following tasks:

```
- name: retrieve file
  get_url:
    url: https://projectcontour.io/quickstart/contour.yaml
    dest: /testing/contour.yaml
  register: download_contour

- name: create deployment
  k8s:
    src: /testing/deployment.yml
  when: download_contour.changed
```

I would like to wait until the contour gets EXTERNAL-IP address assigned, then continue with other tasks. Here is an example on my local computer:

```
kubectl get -n projectcontour service envoy -o wide                                                                       
NAME    TYPE           CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP      PORT(S)                      AGE     SELECTOR
envoy   LoadBalancer   10.96.226.84   172.18.255.200   80:31092/TCP,443:30362/TCP   2d15h   app=envoy
```

How to wait until the `envoy` LoadBalancer gets the EXTERNAL-IP address assigned in Ansible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I haven't tested it, but I think you could try to do something like this:

```
- shell: if [[ $(kubectl get services envoy -n projectcontour --output jsonpath='{.status.loadBalancer.ingress[0]}') ]]; then exit 0; else exit 1; fi;
  register: wait_for_ext_ip
  until: wait_for_ext_ip.rc == 0
  retries: 10
  delay: 5
```

Comment: Yes exactly. I didn't see this answer before I was working on mine. But this could work indeed.

Comment: What does `until: wait_for_ext_ip | success` mean?

Comment: Should it be 0 instead sucess?

Comment: How does the return structure from shell look like?

Comment: ups, thanks, corrected to `wait_for_ext_ip.rc == 0` :)

Answer (score 1):

You should use the [until loops](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#do-until-loops):

```yaml
tasks:
  - name: run kubectl to retreive external IP - Wait for task to complete
    shell: "kubectl get -n projectcontour service envoy -o wide | awk '{ print $4}' |  grep -v EXT"
    register: k_ext_ip
    until: k_ext_ip.stdout.find("1.2.3.4") != -1
    retries: 6
    delay: 10
```

For the shell command, I simply used some basic linux commands. It's better to replace those with Kubectl aligned commands to view only the EXTERNAL-IP.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, thanks to Joelazar for his answer, and it was marked as correct. However, I don't know how it can work because if the loadBalancer external IP isn't assigned, we also get a 0 status code in response.

I prefer using the k8s_info module so we can check if the IP is assigned or not without using the shell module:

```
- name: Get an existing Service object
  kubernetes.core.k8s_info:
    context: kind-test-dev-usa
    api_version: v1
    kind: Service
    name: istio-eastwestgateway
    namespace: istio-system
  register: gateway_service
  until: gateway_service.resources[0].status.loadBalancer.ingress[0].ip is defined
  retries: 10
  delay: 10

- debug:
    var: gateway_service.resources[0].status.loadBalancer
```

This code will check if the external IP is assigned and wait until it is assigned.